# calling a js file in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I'm trying to load a .js file to it. For some reason I can't get it to work.

The js file is at http://www.leadcomm.net/pricequotejs.js

and I put this in the footer:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if (window.location.href == 'http://www.leadcomm.net/cost-estimate/') {    
     var js = document.createElement('script');
     js.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
     js.setAttribute("src", "pricequotejs.js");
     document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
 } 
 </script>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

this is not the proper manner to use a js file in wordpress. 
first you need to save your js file in a folder named js on you theme folder. then open your header.php file and use this add this line :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/your_file.js"></script>
```

this will load your js file to wordpress website.
Happy coding!

Comment: how can I get that to run only one page though?

Comment: in your header.php file you can use 
<?php is_page('455')
{
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/your_file.js"></script>
} ?>
use this code. hope  it help.

Comment: also if you page is homepage then use this:
<?php is_home() { <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/your_file.js"></script> } ?>

Answer (score 0):

I left the document onload function. silly me...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you can't use a standard HTML script tag?

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/pricequotejs.js"></script>
</head>
```