# on mouse enter implementation

Tags: html, css

I have this below code implemented on a wordpress page.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  display: none;
}

p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img src="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />

<div class="child">
<img src="http://maui.hawaii.edu/tlc/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2013/11/testing.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />
</div>
</div>
```

and I am interested to make some changes on it :

1. fade in when the `child` appear instead of `parent` **onmouseenter**
2. remain `child` after the mouse left the picture area and change back
   to `parent` only by the next **mouseenter**.(something like [this](http://heydays.no/));

I've found a [page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove_over_enter) with some details and I think that **onmouseenter** function could be a place to start but I am not so sure how can I implement these specs.

Any thoughts?

Comment: sadly a nonconstructive comment, but all of this is very confusing. Hovering inside of your linked example is very confusing... I just wanted to say this is very confusing.

Comment: You need some jQuery/JavaScript to make this work, CSS alone won't do it.

Comment: @cayce maybe 'cause it's a piece extracted from another code text-on-text with hover option but I wanted to simplify things. As a newbie at this point I am trying to accommodate with code language & stuff. Just please take in consideration the live example running on that site :D mr.Marc, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you clarify the desired behaviour?

Comment: I'll try again. I have two pictures or two text slides, or two <div> 's like in the above mentioned example code.When the mouse pointer enter in the <div> area, the `child` <div> will show up with fade in effect. When the mouse pointer left the <div> area, the `child` will be still there and will turn to `parent` on the next mouse enter.I Hope I was clear enough, please use the example site to watch the effect :D thank you,

Comment: Then I took a good guess with my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using JavaScript to listen for mouse enters and CSS for transitions:

```js
var shown = true;
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var child = document.querySelector('.child');

parent.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  child.style.opacity = shown ? 0 : 1;
  shown = !shown;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}


p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img src="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />

<div class="child">
<img src="http://maui.hawaii.edu/tlc/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2013/11/testing.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW that's it with one quetion please, how can I implement the js on the wordpress page? using a specified plugin or ... is there any possibility to integrated somehow in the <html> field ?

Comment: You need to inject it into HTML somehow... the quickest way would be to edit the footer and put the above code within script tags just before you close the body tag. If not that, I'm sure there are tons of plugins (even some themes have it) that allow you to insert custom JS.

Comment: Thank you so so much, I'll search high and low for that :) I really appreciate it !

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. :)  Here's an interesting article about using JavaScript in WP: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Comment: Good to know, I'll start studying seriously this page.Thank you once again!

Comment: hey there, still around? :) I've injected the footer.php with the provided js code, and it's work as it's shown above (with 2 pictures on mouse enter). It doesn't suppose to affect any kind of `parent`/`child` <div>'s ?  I have a different situation, it's true a little bit more complex with text instead of pictures and it doesn't work. Any thoughts? here is the codepen [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPBZNo)

Comment: You don't need this: `.parent:hover .child {
  display: none;
}`  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEqWmK

Comment: I have no words to thank you again! what can I say, u're one of a kind :D I just saved hours of reading/searching/testing. thank you Shomz !!!

Comment: me again :P wanted to figure out, using a different technique with external js file, I have tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119290/calling-a-js-file-in-wordpress/12119414#12119414) but the strange thing is that everything is working just fine on the page when the js should do its job and on any other pages like [this one](http://goo.gl/DkuFmq) for example, I receive an error in the console.Also I 've used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119290/calling-a-js-file-in-wordpress#comment16354447_12119414) method but again something  went wrong.Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, seems like you're missing the `.parent` element on that page. I like your script name! ;)

Comment: Thanks, I like it too, it's a tribute actually :) true the `.parent` element is missing and the `.child` too.In fact, the whole part because I didn't implemented the `css` above mentioned `code` on that page, I don't need it.That's the tricky part.The `js` affect the pages without that `css` implemented.I feel that somehow I can use your code in the way [Gaurav](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119290/calling-a-js-file-in-wordpress/12119414#12119414) presented, defining a page id but something is missing.Could be a problem that I've used `footer.php` instead of `header.php`?

Comment: No, the loading of the file is fine, either as a separate file or inline. Also, loading it in the footer is fine (even better). The problem is that you need to define which elements are interacting since you no longer have .parent and .child... just fix that, apply the similar CSS to them and it will work.

Comment: I had the white screen of death on my site in the last few hours not so sure how it was displayed on your side :) I've made some nasty tests.Getting back, I'm affraid that I don't catch the idea, should I copy paste the `custom css` code with `.parent/.child` elements no matter what page it is, even if I don't have `.parent/.child` elements on that page? in this page for example I have only one slider revolution element without mouseenter js effect http://goo.gl/DkuFmq. An example will be much appreciate it.

Comment: Those examples have nothing to do with the original question and the answer I gave you. I see you're using Revolution slider, I think you can set it up so it changes slides on mouse enter. Anyway, we're way beyond the scope of the original question, try posting a new one with these specific requirements.

Comment: u're right :) I'll try to figure out somehow and If I don't succeed I'll come back with another new question. Tks

Comment: No problem. Oh and I forgot to answer the parent/child question. I meant you take the CSS I gave you and apply it to the appropriate elements on your page. It won't make sense to refer to .parent and .child elements if they don't exist. :)

Comment: I have copied the `css code` in [this page](http://neuegrid.com/?page_id=2474) but the error it's still there. I've started another separate topic, maybe someone will know a clean way to define which page to be affected by the `js` code.

Comment: Make sure you modify the JS part as well. Look at this: `var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var child = document.querySelector('.child');` They are still looking for .parent and .child elements. It's not going to be a simple copy'n'paste fix. :)

Comment: unfortunately I'm a pure noob that I can understand in a logic way `css` / `HTML` but `php`/ `js` it's not my strong point.That's why I am trying to put together some infos in order to have the desired result. If I change the JS part, I think that I have to use an `if` or something but I have no idea how to implement this... :)

Comment: Don't worry about it, all of us were noobs at some point, just keep working and you'll be great! About the JS part, I was never clear what exactly you wanted: if you have elements that you use **instead** of parent/child, then you just need to change the selector part, like this: `var parent = document.querySelector('.someOtherClassName');` However, if you wish to use the code only on **some** pages, then it might be the best idea simply not to load that JS on those pages; but you can use ifs, of course, to check whether the elements exists and then decide whether to run the code or not.

Comment: I wish to use the code **only** on some predefined pages by id number :) more than that, I am trying to do it in an elegant way using the `script-calls.php` file, registering there the `js`.  Hope to solve this with some help.

Comment: Hey there @Shomz , I have a question regarding this code. Do you have any idea why lately become a kind of altereted? if you'll look at the above code snippet in Chrome, u'll see the fade-in/out sometimes skipping. Any thoughts? tks

Comment: Hi, hmmmm... not sure I was able to reproduce that on my latest Chrome/Ubuntu, maybe they've changed something in order to optimize it. Does it help if you move the listener from the parent element to the body element (or document)?

Comment: I do this if I knew how :) can you please post a codepen or jsfiddle link? If I confirm we can edit the main answer, but not yet. I really appreciate it. https://jsfiddle.net/dsqztvb4/15/

Comment: Don't edit this one, if it's a real problem, just open another question. I meant instead of `parent.addEventListener`, you can do `document.addEventListener` (or body). https://jsfiddle.net/dsqztvb4/16/

Comment: the same and using the `body` I receive an error telling me that the `body` is not defined. that mens in css or ... (!?) Anyway. if this helps, [here](http://goo.gl/2kM9j) is an example but i cand find the responsable source code ...

Comment: Well, you need to define or select the body... or use `document.body`. But I think it's probably going to behave the same way.

Comment: I just tested your website and I like how it works, I really tried going crazy with the mouse, but all the transitions were fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88320/discussion-between-typo-78-and-shomz).