# OnMouseEnter code alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code snippet originally made by [Shomz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29548621/4642215) (special thanks) but lately the solution is messing around (fade in-out effect sometimes is skipping) in Chrome - tested in v45.0.2454.99 m (64-bit) and also v45.0.2454.85 m (64-bit), Win7 64-bit;

```js
var shown = true;
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var child = document.querySelector('.child');

parent.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  child.style.opacity = shown ? 0 : 1;
  shown = !shown;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}


p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img src="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />

<div class="child">
<img src="http://maui.hawaii.edu/tlc/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2013/11/testing.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />
</div>
</div>
```

The code should work like we have in [this](http://goo.gl/2kM9j) example.
At this point, I am interested in your `JS`/`jQuery`/`CSS` code alternatives. Is there any possibility to rewrite the code in order to be functional in latest versions of Chrome too? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery all you need to do is use `fadeToggle()`

```js
$('.parent').mouseenter(function(){
  $('.child').fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}


p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<img src="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />

<div class="child">
<img src="http://maui.hawaii.edu/tlc/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2013/11/testing.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, right now I can't test it using the above mentioned latest versions of Chrome but I'll come back with news. Btw, a little bit offtopic, do you have any idea why `mouseenter` works only if the mouse will enter from bottom to top or top to bottom not from right to left too (in full screen)? tks

Comment: @typo_78 Because `.parent` has a width of `100%` covering the whole screen. Rather than the width of the picture itself.

Comment: _Huston, everything is looking good_ :) thank you, tested in Chrome 45.0.2454.99 m (64-bit) win7 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

The event `onmouseenter` is probably the problem. This event is fired more than you might think when you have nested DOM. There is a great writeup on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) but the quick solution is to try `onmouseover` instead.